# How to resolve conflict in pull request?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Suppose I have two branches, develop and release_v1, and I want to merge the release_v1 branch into develop.

I do a pull request to merge release_v1 to develop, but, after the pull request has been done, I discover that there is a conflict

How can I solve the conflict?  which are the steps to perform?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try googling? Atlassian has a document answering your question

  https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-merge-conflicts-704414003.html

Answer (score 15):

> How can I solve the conflict? which are the steps to perform?

Once you have conflicts follow those steps to fix it:

```
# clean your local working directory with a stash or commit

# update your local repo with the content of the remote branches
git fetch --all --prune

# checkout the release_v1 branch
git checkout release_v1 

# update the content if required
git pull origin release_v1 

# merge the desired branch
git merge origin/master
```

At this point, your release_v1 contains the content of the 2 branches with the conflicts
And now in your conflicts.

Once you have done with that

```
# add the fixed conflicts and commit
git add . && git commit 
git push origin release_v1
```

Go back to your git server and now you will be able to merge the pull request since all conflicts are resolved

Comment: Doesn't this method make it look like *release_v1* includes all the changes that have happened between the base of the branch and *origin/master*?